# How much energy in form of heat does a human body emit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, everyday-life, biophysics, estimation

How much energy in form of heat does a human body emit at rest level?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That's easy. The energy requirement of an average man is 2,500 Calories per day, and one Calorie is 4184J. Therefore he emits about 10.5MJ/day or about 120W.

An average woman requires 2,000 Calories per day, so she emits about 97W.

Comment: Does the human body emit as heat, all the energy it got from food? If yes, in typing this answer, you spent some energy - what is its energy source?

Comment: @New_new_newbie: assuming your weight stays the same you are emitting all the energy from your food as heat. If you're getting fatter it means you're retaining some of the energy and converting it to chemical energy (i.e. fat). Conversely if you're getting thinner it means you're converting chemical energy in fat to heat, so you're emitting more heat than you get from your food. I got the energy to type this from my body [reacting glucose with oxygen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbohydrate_metabolism) to produce water, carbon dioxide and energy.

Comment: Wrong. Energy gets stored in human body as ATPs (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adenosine_triphosphate). The chemical energy stored as a P-O bond gets released. Of course, some part of that will be lost as heat, but if picking up a 400g stone to 1m height required 4J of work, that 4J does come from the food you have consumed. Otherwise energy conservation would stand violated, if your ``input = output as heat'' conjecture was true. So, again, what is the energy source of typing this post if all the energy you got from food got EMITTED out as heat?

Comment: @New_new_newbie: the article you link has in its second paragraph: *ATP is therefore continuously recycled in organisms*. ATP is not used for long term storage. Medium term storage is as [glycogen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycogen) and long term storage is as fat.

Comment: @New_new_newbie: yes, if I lift a weight some of the energy I get from food has been converted to potential energy of the weight. So I suppose it would be more precise to say the energy from food ends as heat + any potential energy gain. In real life we are unlikely to make any long term potential energy changes to our environment (I suppose builders do, though their buildings will fall down eventually so the energy ends up as heat eventually).

Comment: Recycled means creation via energy you get from food, and this energy getting released when required. Besides, there is no overall conservation law for how many ATPs in human body at any fixed time. Also it doesn't say emitted as heat. Anyways, what about energy conservation?

Comment: Sorry I typed the previous one when you were responding.

Comment: 1. Why just potential energy? Energy for doing all the work you do comes from food. \\ 2. I never said we permanently gain energy and store it in some form. It is all dynamic, of course. But if everything that went into us, went out ``as heat'', we physicists would have a lot of trouble justifying energy conservation.

Comment: It's worth noting that ~100 W is the average over 24 hours, including time spent sleeping. Cyclists using power meters may transfer 400 W *to their bicycles*. When I bought an air conditioner for an enclosed industrial-type space I was advised to allow for 500 W per person (although maybe I got sold, because that was a *great* air conditioner).

Comment: From discussions with an architect a long time ago, his rule of thumb for an inactive person (watching a movie) was about 100W.  The radiation calculation is misleading since people here on Earth aren't radiating into deep space, but instead are surrounded by things not very different in temperature than themselves (relative to 2.8K CMB).

Comment: I think this is approximately correct. It depends how much work you do. I'm guessing it's roughly correct for a cyclist too since they just consume more calories. Running can consume 1000 calories/hr. Not sure what fraction as heat.

Comment: A substantial portion of the food that you eat is protein.  Much of this protein is used to maintain muscle mass (conservation of mass) rather than generate heat.  In order to answer this question, it would probably be necessary to do a complete heat and material balance on the food that a person eats, which would require a careful accounting of the caloric content of all food and waste products that the person deals with.

Comment: If I carry a heavy rock from the bottom of a mountain up to the top, and I leave it there, then at least _some_ of the calories that I have eaten have not been converted to heat...  At least, not _yet_.  But then, even if the rock eventually is disturbed and it rolls back down the hill, slightly heating itself and other things along the way; that's heat that was not radiated _from my body_.

Comment: @jameslarge Of course it's not *exactly* true, but you're missing the point - this is a *great* back-of-the-hand calculation that gives you something very close to the real value for the average Joe. Even if you did nothing all day but eat and put heavy objects up, almost all the energy you got in would be released as heat. Mammals are *extremely* inefficient heat engines - depending on the amount of work you do, the effective "food -> work done" efficiency is somewhere around 20% to as low as *1%*. And the upper limit is the "cycle all day" kind, not "workout a bit once a day".

Comment: Hi Rizwan. Thanks for the suggested edit, but note that a *Calorie* with a capital *C*, is a thousand *calories, with a small *c*.

Comment: " assuming your weight stays the same you are emitting all the energy from your food as heat" ehmmm, what about , you know, excretions?

Comment: moving a 100kg weight up a flight of stairs (3m) is about 3000 joule. To be on the same order of magnitude of the resting metabolism you would need to do that about once every 30 seconds in average (day and night). A more "reasonable" once every minute for 8 hours a day for 5 days a week would be about 12W in average.

Comment: There could be a significant difference instead if you consider that not all energy from food is absorbed by the body, some of it is directly excreted out as poop or biological material produced by bodies (hairs, nails, nose boogies). This would be expelled as chemical energy and not contribute to the total heat. I don't know how big that is though, and if anyone has ever bothered to measure it, but it could affect the result.

Comment: I would expect that the energy loss to excrement is quite significant. As a thought experiment, imagine taking all the food you will eat in a day, dehydrating it completely, and then burning it in a room to heat the room. Now contrast that with taking a day's worth of poop, dehydrating it completely and then burning it in the room. The difference in heat output from the fires is the amount of energy absorbed and used by your body in a day. Again I don't know the numbers but dry poop burns quite well; I'm sure it's not negligible.

Answer (score 7):

I hesitate to contradict John, but: it's simplistic to assume caloric input equals caloric output, or that caloric output is purely heat, as opposed to moving from one place to another, lifting boxes, etc.  A far better model IMHO is to set up the human body as a black-body source with $\epsilon = 0.98 $ (emissivity),  temperature = 310K, and some reasonable estimate as to total body area.  Then you compare the absorption of heat from, say an ambient environment of 294K to see the net outflow of heat.

That does ignore conductive and convective heat flow :-) .

See, for example, the excellent calculator at [hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/bodrad.html)

Comment: Yes, I recall that the result using Stefan-Boltzmann's law is close to that of John Rennie. In space, the power output is close to $1 kW$, quite impressive!

Comment: I expect that black body radiation losses are small compared to other heat losses of the human body in most ordinary circumstances.  I haven't done the numbers, but I betcha the heat loss from inhaling gas at ambient temperature and exhaling it at body temperature is much greater than black body radiation when sitting behind a desk in a typical office.  Add to that evaporative cooling since exhaled breath usually contains more moisture.

Comment: Unless you're building a ziggurat or otherwise storing lots of gravitational potential, don't you think all of that mechanical energy also ends up as heat?

Comment: @rob, yeah, most of it does.  But just think of the stored entropy that comes from learning a bunch of stuff (highly ordered :-) neuron structures).

Comment: @Carl Well, if I commit a terabyte of information to memory (seems unreasonably large), the minimum entropy change is $S=k\ln2^{40}\approx 1200\,\mathrm{K/eV}$. At my body temperature the minimum energy release is only about 1/4 eV. Even if the ratio of physical to information entropy is a billion to one I still have much less than a joule of heat associated with learning. I don't think it's a big correction.

Comment: The question asks for the rest case. So no moving boxes.

Comment: Upvotes all round - I love the way a simple question can kick off a discussion :-)

Comment: @ rob - I think the question wasn't about what happens eventually. `OP' talked about, e.g. what an IR scanner would see - how much heat is getting emitted in a certain short span. Nothing survives eventually, even ziggurats, but that's not the point. :)

Comment: This answer means that, during a hot summer week in my really hot appartment, I emit no heat, and I will directly convert all my food calories into work at 100% efficiency. During summer, I regularly break the 2nd law of thermodynamics.

Comment: The human body is not just a black body (in the thermodinamic sense). The human body actively expels water to evaporate as a way to control temperature. The radiative emission is relevant when conduction/convention are excluded, e.g. how fast a dead body in space would cool down.

Comment: @pqnet I agree that some energy is dispersed via the transition energy from liquid to gaseous water, but you can still get a decent approximation just using black-body calculations

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I'm arguing that it is not. The reason the result is in the same order of magnitude is pure luck, due to gross overestimation of the radiative emission, and in reality the radiative emission is a lot less significant (at least for clothed individuals or people in warm environment - which includes basically all steady state humans).
Outer skin/clothes temperature is significantly lower than 36 degrees normally (the body temperature you measure at 36 is in enclosed part of the skin such as the armpit - which is not usually exchanging radiation with the rest of the world)

Answer (score 6):

John Rennie's answer is correct +/- 1% or so.

Sure, you can lift something up, doing work instead of emitting heat. But you equally often lift something *down*, converting its potential energy to heat that your body emits.  Besides, most of the loads you lift are small compared to the energy "cost" of running the chemical factory that is your body.

Or say you climb up the stairs in a 20-story building.  Assuming 1 floor = 10', that's 200 ft-lb. of work, or around 270J. Let's say that takes you 2 minutes, during which your body emits 120*100 = 12,000J of heat.  So the work you did amounts to only about 2% of the total energy you consumed during that stair climb.  And a modern human doesn't do physical work for very much of the day, so the conversion to work amounts to less than 1% error.

Besides, you (usually) climb down about as much as you climb up -- again converting your potential energy to heat -- so that pretty much cancels out.

Just assume that it takes around 100W to run your body at idle, more if you have to do "work" (running, etc.)

Comment: Umm... you forgot to include the weight of the person in your 200 ft stair climb calculation! A typical person can provide over 100W of sustained mechanical power, elite athletes can do closer to 500W.  Sprint exertion is perhaps double.

Tempted to edit this answer...

Comment: @Michael and bgold: we're not very efficient in converting chemically stored energy into mechanical work. IIRC, around 20 % for running, up to 25 % for biking. So when our output is 100 W mechanical, we have at the same time an additional output of 300 - 400 W in form of heat. When lifting something down, we're not only emitting heat due to the loss in potential energy of the weight but also additional head from our muscles (lifting things down makes hungry as well!)

Comment: The better point of contention should not be useful work, but the residual calorie in what humans excrete (poop, fart methane, sebum, etc.). doi:10.1002/oby.22965 says poop energy is seven percent of what you eat. (Caloric bioavailability is different from spending energy to get energy — spending is heat, pooping out isn’t.)

Answer (score 2):

As a rough planning figure for building design etc, 1 human = 100 watt.