# Why do satellites not burn up in space?

Tags: thermodynamics, rocket-science, satellites

I really liked  [Pentane's](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/63055/pentane) response to another question on this site about  [Heat Transfer in Space](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/159590/heat-transfer-from-a-spaceship-in-deep-space/159669#159669) .

My question is this, how do spaceflight capsules or satellites maintain their integrity? Given that one side of the satellite in isolation will be exposed to extreme high temperatures and yet the other side would be exposed to very low temperatures. The temperature would also be cyclic every time an orbit of the earth occurs. I know that spacesuits have cooling/heat transfer systems built in but it seems improbable that we could build a system in a spacesuit/satellite/capsule to deal with this.

I think I am missing something fundamental, can someone help fill in my blanks?

Answer (score 1):

> The temperature would also be cyclic every time an orbit of the earth occurs.

For some hardened space probes, you may need the solar panels to provide the spacecraft  with the maximum of light, as long as you hide the delicate components on the shadowed part of the spacecraft.

For others, they will only be exposed to sunlight for part of their orbit, although geostationary orbiting satellites such as TV relay stations  have to be built to take the conditions.

Unlike satellites which orbit the Earth, there is little  possibility of a shadow from the Sun for those vehicles which travel beyond the Earth.

> I think I am missing a fundamental. Can you help fill in my blank?

From Wikipedia  [Reducing Apollo Spacecraft Temperature Increases.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_8)

NASA being NASA, a simple roll is transformed into **Passive Thermal Control**

> The crew now placed the spacecraft into Passive Thermal Control (PTC), also called "barbecue roll", in which the spacecraft rotated about once per hour around its long axis to ensure even heat distribution across the surface of the spacecraft. In direct sunlight, the spacecraft could be heated to over 200 °C (392 °F) while the parts in shadow would be −100 °C (−148 °F). These temperatures could cause the heat shield to crack and propellant lines to burst. Because it was impossible to get a perfect roll, the spacecraft swept out a cone as it rotated. The crew had to make minor adjustments every half hour as the cone pattern got larger and larger.[30]